# Arquitetura API RestFul

Tags: api, rest, spring-mvc, arquitetura-de-software, restful

Estou construindo uma API RESTFul com spring MVC e tenho 2 requisitos não funcionais que não estou entendendo como atacá-los.

1. A API deve suportar 100 requisições por segundo;
2. A API deverá prever
   falhas de integração entre as APIs, não deixando o cliente sem
   nenhuma resposta.

Quais componentes do spring mvc posso utilizar para atender esse 2 requisitos? Ou como posso plantear a arquitetura? Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. A API deve suportar 100 requisições por segundo.

Vamos separar as responsabilidade aqui.

**A responsabilidade do desenvolvedor** é criar uma API performática, que suporte requisições simultâneas e clusterizadas, ou seja, pode existir mais de uma instância da API, rodando em servidores diferentes, conectando inúmeros usuários à mesma base dados.

Quer dizer que, se sua API receber, por exemplo, de duas origens diferentes, uma requisição de excluir e de atualizar uma mesma informação, sua aplicação deve tratar isso sem conflitos, incoerência, e sem perda de performance.

**A responsabilidade do devops** é de criar uma hospedagem da sua aplicação, onde possa escalar individualmente, e sem necessidade de haver alterações na aplicação, pontos específicos da solução - escalar, horizontalmente ou verticalmente, apenas a API, ou apenas o banco de dados, ou o storage, etc.

Os dois somados é onde você irá chegar no seus "100 req/sec".

**Exemplo**, a média geral de latência - tempo entre *request* e *response* - da sua aplicação é de 60ms vazia - com apenas um cliente - mas a partir de 500 clientes a latencia sobe para 100ms. Após investigar, percebe-se que o gargalo é o processamento da API - visto que, superficialmente, pode ser acesso ao banco de dados, acesso à storage, conexão de rede - então escalar a API é o início da solução. Agora deve-se investigar e decidir por escalar horizontalmente - criar mais instâncias da sua API respondendo aos seus clientes, com devido *load balance* - ou verticalmente - aumentando os recursos alocados para sua aplicação, como mais *cores* ou memória, aumentando o poder de processamento.

Essas orientações são bem superficiais, principalmente pois não sabemos qual o negócio da API. Se for apenas processar dados - sem conectar à nenhuma base de dados ou storage - é mais simples que fazer isso com uma API que faz interpretação de imagens, que requer acesso é vários outros recursos, e ainda tem característica de ser *processing intensive*.

> 2. A API deverá prever falhas de integração entre as APIs, não deixando o cliente sem nenhuma resposta.

Podem existir vários *approaches* para esse requisito. Para começar, pode-se definir alguns *filters*. Assim, sua aplicação poderá interceptar requisições no *request* e no *response*. Tendo alguma falha, trata-se alí e retorna um contexto de exceção padronizado para seu cliente.

Eu não gosto disso. E, não tenho certeza, mas acredito que não seja uma boa prática. O ideal, IMHO, é validar os dados da *request*, se houver problemas, retorna um **HTTP 400 - Requisição inválida**, e de der realmente falha na sua API, retorna **HTTP 500 - Erro interno de servidor**.

Será **muito estranho** uma API retornar algo diferente de HTTP 500, mas no corpo da resposta vir que deu um falha.

Recomendo que dê uma lida nesse [guia de projeto para uma API](https://github.com/Gutem/http-api-design). Tem várias orientações bem legais.